# get property in html class

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps and two properties for the coordinates(long and lat). I have also a html class, like this:

```
  </html:div>
          <html:div class="geoCard">
                    <xf:input ref="{{fieldname}}/longitude" appearance="{{properties/appearance}}"  class="geolocation_long">
                          <xf:label>{{properties/label}}</xf:label>
                      </xf:input>  
                    <xf:input ref="{{fieldname}}/latitude" appearance="{{properties/appearance}}"  class="geolocation_lat">
                          <xf:label>{{properties/label}}</xf:label>
                      </xf:input>  
          </html:div>
```

So I want the google coordinates showing with that html class.

The javascript is like this:

```
var map;

if (typeof initMap == 'function') {
    initMap();
}

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: { lat: 52.001321, lng: 4.374577 }
        //mapTypeControl: false
    });

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    });
}//end function initMap

function toggleBounce() {
    if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
}

var marker;
var infowindow;
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
        infowindow.close();
    }

    if (typeof marker != 'undefined') {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }

    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                draggable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: "Drag me!"
            });

            document.getElementById(marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)).className += "geolocation_long";
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<p>Marker Location:'
                    + 'lat: ' + marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)
                    + ', '
                    + 'lng: ' + marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6)
                    + '</p>'            


        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
            if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
                infowindow.close();
            }
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<p>Marker Location:'
                    + 'lat: ' + event.latLng.lat().toFixed(6)
                    + ', '
                    + 'lng: ' + event.latLng.lng().toFixed(6)
                    + '</p>'
            });

            infowindow.open(map, marker);


        });

        infowindow.open(map, marker);




        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
            if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

So I try to get the value from the coordinates in the html class, like this:

```
 document.getElementById(marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)).className += "geolocation_long";
```

but then I get the error:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'className' of undefined or null reference

Thank you

ok, I just have a textbox, like this:

```
<input name="form_inp16" title="" class="xforms-input xforms-control geolocation_long xforms-ap-default" id="form_inp16" type="text" value="">
```

So I want the value from this property: marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)

in the textbox:

Thank you

I have added a screenshot. SO you see a infobox with two coorinates. So the first coordinate  have to be shown in the textfield Geo.

So how to do this?

Thank you[image]

Comment: Can you provide the actual markup you are working with?

Comment: `<xf:label>{{properties/label}}</xf:label>` is not HTML

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/eB2RX/1/

Comment: I have added the same in answer. Do check. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general with a unique "id":

```
document.getElementById("form_inp16").value=marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6);
document.getElementById("form_inp17").value=marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6);
```

If you want to populate those form fields on a "click" of the marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(e) {
    document.getElementById("form_inp16").value=marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6);
    document.getElementById("form_inp17").value=marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/16ju71Ls/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To get details of marker like address or latLng, you need to use the Geocoder service.

```js
var map;

if (typeof initMap == 'function') {
    initMap();
}

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: { lat: 52.001321, lng: 4.374577 }
        //mapTypeControl: false
    });

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    });
}//end function initMap

function toggleBounce() {
    if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
}

var marker;
var infowindow;
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
        infowindow.close();
    }

    if (typeof marker != 'undefined') {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }

    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                draggable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: "Drag me!"
            });

            document.getElementById(marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)).className += "geolocation_long";
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<p>Marker Location:'
                    + 'lat: ' + marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)
                    + ', '
                    + 'lng: ' + marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6)
                    + '</p>'            


        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
            //Get the details
            var markerDetails = getAddress(event.latLng);  

            if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
                infowindow.close();
            }
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<p>Marker Location:'
                    + 'lat: ' + event.latLng.lat().toFixed(6)
                    + ', '
                    + 'lng: ' + event.latLng.lng().toFixed(6)
                    + '</p>'
            });

            infowindow.open(map, marker);


        });

        infowindow.open(map, marker);




        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
            if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        });

         var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         function getAddress(latLng) {
            geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng},
               function(results, status) {
                 if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                     console.log(results[0]);  
                 }
            });
         }
      }

    });
}
```